# Remove local storage data when browser/tab close in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){            
  window.localStorage.clear();
}
```

Here in this code the localstorage gets clear but on refresh page it clears the localStorage that i dont want.
Help me...

Comment: You're describing session storage - are you able to rewrite your code to use it instead of local storage?

Answer (score -1):

`localStorage.clear();` will clear all the data from local storage.There is no need of page refresh to get the changes.

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/7vDpmbM477QmhtatbjxA?p=preview)

Please provide a Verifiable example that produces the problem.

Comment: when we hard reload it will clear the local storage.
that shouldn't happen.

Comment: No, when you do hard reload the data in local storage wont be deleted.Only data in local storage will be deleted when you close all tabs or you clear your browser cookies manually.